# Getting "0:1(1) error: Unexpected NEW_IDENTIFIER" when trying to compile my vertex shader

Tags: c++, glsl

I'm trying to rewrite the shader loader I was using, and I keep getting the title error when I try to compile my program.  My search of related questions turned up [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877386/opengl-shader-compilation-errors-unexpected-undefined-at-token-undefined) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28527956/get-011-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-when-trying-to-compile-shader) topics which suggested that the issue might be with my use of strings, so I tried copying the loaded shaders from string objects to arrays, and it's still happening. Here's the relevant section of my Initialize function:

```
// Begin shader loading
vertShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
fragShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

// Vertex shader first
vertShaderCode = loader.read("vs.txt");

char codeHolder[vertShaderCode.size() + 1];
std::size_t length = vertShaderCode.copy(codeHolder, vertShaderCode.size(), 0);
codeHolder[length] = '\0';

const char* tmp1 = codeHolder;

// Compile the vertex shader
glShaderSource(vertShader, 1, &tmp1, NULL);
glCompileShader(vertShader);
```

This is a little more verbose than is probably necessary, but I was trying to be very explicit so I didn't miss anything.

I know my shader loader class is working fine, because in the section where I'm checking the compilation status and printing out error messages, I added in some code to check to make sure everything was being passed correctly:

```
//check the compile status
glGetShaderiv(vertShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &shader_status);
if (!shader_status) 
    {
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("verification.txt");
    fout << vertShaderCode << endl;

    int index = 0;
    while(tmp1[index] != '\0' && index < 1000)
        {
        fout << tmp1[index];
        index++;
        }
    fout << endl;
    index = 0;
    while(codeHolder[index] != '\0' && index < 1000)
        {
        fout << codeHolder[index];
        index++;
        }
    fout.close();

    GLchar InfoLog[1024];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(vertShader, sizeof(InfoLog), NULL, InfoLog);
    fprintf(stderr, "Vertex Shader %d: '%s'\n", vertShader, InfoLog);
    return false;
    }
```

the "verification.txt" file ends up with three copies of the shader code as I would expect:

```
attributevec3v_position;attributevec3v_color;varyingvec3color;uniformmat4mvpMatrix;voidmain(){gl_Position=mvpMatrix*vec4(v_position,1.0);color=v_color;}
attributevec3v_position;attributevec3v_color;varyingvec3color;uniformmat4mvpMatrix;voidmain(){gl_Position=mvpMatrix*vec4(v_position,1.0);color=v_color;}
attributevec3v_position;attributevec3v_color;varyingvec3color;uniformmat4mvpMatrix;voidmain(){gl_Position=mvpMatrix*vec4(v_position,1.0);color=v_color;}
```

I know the rest of my program works fine, too, as it works perfectly if I just hard code the shaders into my application program.

Thanks in advance, this is super annoying.

Edit: Here's my makefile

```
# Linux
CC=g++
LIBS= -lglut -lGLEW -lGL

# Compiler flags
CXXFLAGS= -g -Wall -std=c++0x

all: ../bin/Matrix

../bin/Matrix: ../src/main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) ../src/main.cpp -o ../bin/Matrix $(LIBS)
```

Comment: `char codeHolder[vertShaderCode.size() + 1];` This is not legal C++. So how does your code compile?

Comment: If that's the case I'm not really sure.  I'm using the VMware player to run a Ubuntu distro, and I'm just compiling it with g++.

And the program is writing out to "verification.txt" correctly, so it's definitely running.

Comment: @NicolBolas I tried changing it from `char codeHolder[vertShaderCode.size() + 1];` to `char codeHolder[2048];` and it didn't change compilation, or the error that I'm getting at the terminal.